# lightning:inputRichText component not working when deployed to new sandbox - quillLib.js error

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have a lightning component that contains a lightning:inputRichText field working in a sandbox. When I deployed the component to another sandbox using ANT, I'm getting an error about quillLib.js as shown below when I try to type in the form.

[image: quillLib.js error occurring on lightning:inputRichText in new sandbox]

Both sandboxes are on API v43.0.

Has anyone seen this error or know why it's happening?
Will raise a case with Salesforce also, as it seems to be an internal error.

Comment: Did you try in another browser? lightning:inputRichText uses quill.js and it could be an issue from that library.

Comment: Yeah, I tried in both Chrome and Safari and the same issue still occurs.

Comment: Update: Raised a case with Salesforce and they confirmed they were able to deploy the component to a new org without any issues. Looks like a problem with our sandboxes and has been escalated to T3 support. To be continued!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to find an answer for this one through some experimentation - it seems that my force:recordData component (which was trying to populate a custom rich text field on my chat object) couldn't access the custom field in any sandboxes past the one where the object and field were originally created.

Even though I had layoutType specified as FULL, I had to specifically include the new "Body__c" field in the fields parameter. This is because I forgot to deploy the layout for the new object that included this field, so the only fields available when I specified "FULL" were the ID and any other required fields.

```
<force:recordData aura:id="chatRecordCreator" 
                      layoutType="FULL"
                      targetRecord="{!v.newChat}"
                      targetFields="{!v.simpleNewChat}"
                      targetError="{!v.newChatError}" 
                      fields="Body__c" />
......

<lightning:inputRichText value="{!v.simpleNewChat.Body__c}" />
```

Seems like there was some internal access issue on the field which was causing the null pointer in the quillLib.js class. Once I specifically provided access to the field on the force:recordData component, it worked.

Some more information on the Lightning Data Service from the Summer '17 highlights [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/06/summer-17-highlight-diving-lightning-data-service.html).

More info about the difference between layoutType and fields attributes [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/data_service_load_record.htm).